# RIA Services WITHOUT Silverlight

Tags: breeze, wcf-ria-services, breeze-sharp

I am new with Ria Services. I'm using VS2013 SP2. I just try to find out: Is it possible to use RIA Services WITHOUT Silverlight?

I do not see any principal contradictions to use Ria Services with any kind of client (standalone wpf app in my case). But....

- As I can see, client side code would be generated for silverlight app or silverlight class lib only
- and that's because of special option "wcf ria serivces link" i silverlight tab of project properties.
- I can not find any command line tool or msbuild target file to generate client code.
- Seems that google doesn't feels difference between "with" and "without" :(
- Official doc says about using ria services in asp.net web project.  More specificall: DomainServiceSource in the same web application. By the way, custom datasource component is compleetly not what I need.

This looks like magic! I can not just imagine who generates client code!

Can anybody throw the light on this problem, or just kick me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to access your DomainService method from a full .NET app like wpf you may resort to exposign a SOAP endpoint and generate a standard wcf proxy, [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davrous/archive/2010/12/03/how-to-open-a-wcf-ria-services-application-to-other-type-of-clients-the-soap-endpoint-3-5.aspx) will help you, bear in mind however that you won't get a DomainContext on your wpf, but rather a standard WCF Proxy that makes "Changes" not as straightforward as with Silverlight's DomainContext

> This looks like magic! I can not just imagine who generates client code!

About who is generating the code, it all depends on the RiaClientCodeGeneratorName property that you put on the Silverlight .csproj, you can tweak it a lot, but is definitely suited for Silverlight.

That being said, if it's an option, I think you'd better to go with [OpenRia](http://www.openriaservices.net/Default.aspx) that is de facto replacing WCF RIA. Despite it doesn't actually address your problem is the only one being developed.

Comment: Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 3):

You might want to take a look at Breeze-sharp: (http://www.breezejs.com/breeze-sharp).  It allows a .NET client to communicate with any web service ( the sample application mentioned below uses a WebApi backend) and the client is very similar to the old RIA services client, but with a number of additional capabilities.

There is also a 'DocCode' sample that shows off many of Breeze's capabilities in the Breeze.Sharp.Samples GitHub repo.